# When to use "zur Verzweiflung" vs "zum Verzweifeln"

Tags: usage

In conversation with my friend, I said:

> Seine Possen haben alle Erwachsenen **zur Verzweiflung** getrieben. Man hätte fast meinen können, dass er es darauf anlegte ...

And I was wondering when I would use "*zum Verzweifeln*", on the other hand. I seem to opt for "*zum Verzweifeln*" when I say something like:

> Ich weiß, die Lage ist echt **zum Verzweifeln**, aber ...

"*Verzweiflung*" and "*Verzweifeln*" may both translate as "*despair*" on the surface, but I get the impression that "*zur Verzweiflung*" and "*zum Verzweifeln*" differ in usage. I can't put my finger on exactly how, though.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *zur **Verzweiflung** treiben* is quite idiomatic. You just wouldn't say *zum **Verzweifeln** treiben*. In general, *treiben* goes with nouns, also when referring to the inner state of people. There's *zur Weißglut treiben*, *in den Wahnsinn treiben*, etc.

On the other hand *X ist zum Y* always takes a (nominalized) infinitive as Y:

> Es ist zum Weinen.
>
> Es ist zum Lachen.
>
> Es ist zum Aus-der-Haut-Fahren
>
> Es ist zum Mäusemelken
>
> Es ist zum Fürchten

This always means that X is such that Y would be a reasonable response to it.

Comment: Your answer is a bit unclear when it says, that _treiben_ in general goes with nouns, since _Verzweifeln_ is also a noun. Maybe you would like to be a bit more specific what you mean and what is the relevant difference between _Verzweifeln_ and _Verzweiflung_ here (merely being a noun cannot be it, since both are nouns).

Answer (score 1):

Nominalized infinitives coin the literal action into a noun. In contrary, the *-ung* noun of a verb is about a concept.

> In diesem Vortrag geht es um das richtige Beleuchten.
>
> In diesem Vortrag geht es um die richtige Beleuchtung.

In this example, it's mostly a matter of style. The first one makes me expect a lot of practical examples, the second one a dreadful narration of an hour.

Sometimes, you have to choose the right verb, too:

> Das bringt mich zum Verzweifeln.
>
> Das treibt mich zur Verzweifelung.

Unfortunately, there's not much logic behind that.